# Is it possible for a WebExtension to download and execute an .msi file?

Tags: firefox, plugins, firefox-addon-webextensions

With a Firefox WebExtension, I'm looking to find a way to download an *.msi* file and execute it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using : 
browser.downloads.download, 
browser.downloads.onChanged.addListener
and 
browser.downloads.open